# Python 2.7: id() built-in function strange behaviour

Tags: python-2.7

What is happening with `id()`? I have the following code:

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([4,5,6])
c = np.asarray([a, b])
id_1 = id(c[0][0]) 
id_2 = id(a[0]) 
id_3, id_4 = id(c[0][0]), id(a[0])
```

`id_1` and `id_2` is different but `id_3` and `id_4` is the same. I'm using Python 2.7.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: I get the same id for all 4 (CPython 3.5 numpy 1.9.3).  What are you doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

This makes me think that each build can handle this function differently.  For Cpython it is the address in memory.

It looks like you are using numpy.  I'm guessing that c actually contains copies of arrays a and b.  Which means that id_1 and id_2 would be different. Similarly I would expect `id_1 == id_3` and `id_2 == id_4`.